# How to configure DNAT on linux PC so that windows PC destination address can NAT to external linux server?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, nat

**Topology:**

Windows PC (Eg.,20.0.0.2) <---> enp6s0 20.0.0.1 [Ubunthu 20.04 as NAT] enp8s0 172.30.18.95<-->eth1 - Linux PC {172.30.18.90}

**Requirement:**

I want to ftp 30.0.0.1 from windows PC, has static route gateway towards 20.0.0.2 and reach ubunthu, DNAT needs to be configured, so that IP 30.0.0.1 would NAT with destination IP address 172.30.18.90 and redirect to enp8s0 and get response.

If we scale no of IP destination from windows PC eg., 30.0.0.x, it has to get response from 172.30.18.90 by doing NAT (on ubunthu PC) in between.

**Tried:**

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp6s0 -j DNAT --to 172.30.18.90
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp6s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

***On Ubunthu PC:***

```
root@labuser-OptiPlex-390:~# sudo iptables -L -v -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 899 packets, 73585 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source    destination
951 66326 DNAT       all  --  enp6s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            to:172.30.18.90

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 42 packets, 3563 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source    destination
5   313 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      enp6s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

root@labuser-OptiPlex-390:~#
```

**Expectation:**

I'm expecting ping 30.0.0.1 which need to get response from 172.30.18.90.

**Observation:**

Ping response - Request timed out. Packets receiving on ubunthu PC but NAT is not happening.

Could anyone help me how to do NAT configuration on ubunthu for my requirement?

Comment: I assume you have ip forwarding enabled in the Ubuntu PC (`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns 1)? Also, does the linux PC have a route back to 20.0.0.2 so that the response goes again through the NAT? Your PREROUTING rule seems correct and sufficient (you don't need the MASQUERADING rule) if the above are checked. If you can not have a valid return route from the linux box, you need to do masquerading in the way going to enp8s0 (SNAT would work too).